# C++, very unexpected -1#INF

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, optimization, nan

I am debugging optimization routine. I produce a log text file where I track objective function value at each iteration in optimization routine.

Here is the context: I work with a curve fitting problem, with a model that is linear in the four parameter, and polynomial in the X data

```
Y = PARAM1*X^3+PARAM2*X^2+PARAM3*X+PARAM4
```

and I run optimization routine on unnoised unbiased data generated from this model so as to test the algorithm.

In log file, first optimization step show no problem. Function evaluations have a double value. At each iteration, 5 function values are calculated (and displayed in log file). From a given iteration, things turn sour: one function evaluation becomes `-1#INF` although objective function has already been successfully evaluated at this very point (!). In the next iterations, the 'bad point' keeps evaluating at `-1#INF`, and one by one other points also end up evaluated at -1#INF. The calculation of Y at these points is no struggle given the formula and given the fact that they were properly evaluated before.

Also, I suspect another cause, like memory management. Would you have any idea about this, or any advice to track the problem closer?

---

## Edit

I see the first occurrence of `-1#INF` in log file. Function is evaluated at 5 points at each iteration, but only one of those 5 points is a 'new point'. When `-1#INF` first appears, function has already been successfully evaluated at this point.

It looks like

```
ITERATION N-1
f1 559.011
f2 560.034
f3 562.034
f4 560.342
f5 560.344

ITERATION N 
f1 -1#INF
f2 560.034
f3 558.034
f4 560.342
f5 560.344
```

where at `ITERATION N` only `f3` is a function evaluation at a new point, and f1 is the function evaluation at the same point than is f1 in `ITERATION N-1`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "successfully evaluated"? Are you sure that neither an overflow nor a division by zero occurred?

Comment: Memory management is doubtfully the problem. Your iterative algorithm is diverging. Try and track down the first calculation that produces INF.

Comment: Use a debugger (or add print statements) to track down the exact line of code that causes the error.

Comment: Almost impossible to help you unless you post some actual code.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I see the first occurence. Function is evaluated at 5 points at each iteration, but only one of those 5 points is a 'new point'. When -1#INF first appears, function has already been successfully evaluated at this point.

Comment: @dlib Okay, now find out why it's produced infinity, and work back to the root cause. We live for the the thrill of the chase… so have fun!

Comment: Just to be clear, the log file ain't good enough. You need to look at every single addition, multiplication, etc that went into that INF. Start at the logged number and painstakingly work backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinity propagates in calculations.  The biggest odds are that the polynomial produced -Inf because X was already -Inf.  With the biggest odds that this is caused by calculation for X that divided by zero.  Work your way back and add code that checks for zero in divisions.

Comment: Thanks. However, vector X used is the same at each calculation from the very beginning... so that if there where any struggle with any operand in polynom, it would have appeared from start. Only variables are parameters, which are multiplicative constants in formula...

Comment: Well, then move the checks to the code that generates the parameter values.  Your snippet is way too brief to give an accurate answer.

Comment: Iterative solvers as he seems to be describing can reach infinity by exponential divergence, without division.

Comment: Because of the norm used, a.o. Problem fixed, sorry guys.